# DevExpress XtraGrid control's Is not showing data in the xtragrid view

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xtragrid

i created one application which uses devexpress xtragrid control. I used xtragrid control on the user control of devexpress. And used that user control on the form. And in the load event of user control i bind the data to the xtragrid control by using datasource property of xtragrid. Problem that i'm facing is that when i'm loading data first time to the xtragrid then it works fine. But after next loading it is showing data to the xtragrid control but it is not showing data to the view of the xtragrid control.

I don't know why this is happening at the second loading. How to resolve this problem?

thanks.

Comment: may you please post code on how you are binding data to your xtragrid control?

Answer (score 0):

You bind it problematically? Or thru the xtragrid designer ?

If you did it programatically, try using the refreshdata method of the gridview...